# Cannot create a mole for Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache abstract class

Tags: .net, moles

Hopefully, this is the correct forum for this question. I am trying to test a class that wraps the `Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache` class. Unfortunately, Moles does not generate a stub for this abstract class so i cannot do the following:

```
MDataCacheFactory.AllInstance.GetCacheString = (DataCacheFactory factory, string aString) =>   

{

   return new MDataCache( new SDataCache());

};
```

`MDataCache` constructor requires a non-null value. So how do i get around this?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Best Practices for Stubs and Moles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798446.aspx), you shouldn't use moles to implement abstract classes, since they are mockable by stub types.

You can achieve this with Moq or with [stubs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798383.aspx).